# Clear a scale component from view matrix. Camera-independent scaling

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I need for my little program to scale a gizmo by camera distance to conveniently move objects at anytime. I think I have two options:

1. Calculate distance from gizmo to camera, make a matrix for scaling, multiply all points in cycle:

   ```
   glm::mat4 scaleMat;
   scaleMat= glm::scale(scaleMat, glm::vec3(glm::distance(cameraPos,gizmoPos)));

   for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
   {
       vertices[i] = glm::vec3(scaleMat * glm::vec4(vertices[i], 1.0));
   }
   ```
2. Clear the scale component of the view (lookAt) matrix only for gizmo.

If I use the first way my scale of gizmo accumulates the scale and increase size of gizmo any time when I change camera position. I think the second way is more accurate, but how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Are you planning to apply a different scaling each time to the same starting object? Editing vertices this way is quite inefficient

Comment: @magicleon Yes, multiplying matrix each time is the reason that strange behavior. I got it. But how to implement the second way?

Comment: What about doing this same scaling at the shader passing the scale-matrix as an uniform?

Comment: @codeNoob the second way I propose is down there in the answers!

Comment: @magicleon Sorry, one last question. How do you think, which is the best way to store a transformation for objects (not for gizmo) - in one matrix or modifing the data? I ask you, because I want to use mouse picker and I want to store actual data for it. May be to multiply a modified matrix exactly in the moment of the mouse picking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply different scaling each time to the same model, you should not manipulate vertexes (you should never do, in fact), but the Model Matrix. Through that you can manipulate the object without processing the vertexes via code.
I would go with something like this:

```
glm::mat4 modelMatrix(1.0f);
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix,glm::vec3(glm::distance(cameraPos,gizmoPos)));
```

This will give you the scaled Model View matrix. Now you only need to pass it to your Vertex Shader.

You should have, roughly, something like this:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

uniform mat4 M;

void main(){
    gl_Position =  M * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
}
```

I have not tested the code but it is really similar to the code of one of my projects. There I keep my model matrix so the scaling is accumulated, but if you pass to the vertex shader a brand new matrix each time, nothing will be remembered.

If you need more about passing the uniform to the shader, have a look [here at my current project's code](https://github.com/magicleon94/OpenGL-Android-TARDIS/tree/master/AndroidTardis).

You can find the scaling inside `TARDIS::applyScaling` and the shader loading in `main.cpp`

Comment: You convinced me to use the first method. :)) But we'll never know how to clear the scale component from the view matrix. :)) Anyway, thank you!

Comment: It's not that hard once you get, I suggest you to try it for the future! Maybe these tutorials can bring some clarity! http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

Comment: Sorry, one last question. How do you think, which is the best way to store a transformation for objects (not for gizmo) - in one matrix or modifing the  data? I ask you, because I want to use mouse picker and I want to store  actual data for it. May be to multiply a modified matrix exactly in the moment of the mouse picking?

Comment: I don't think I've understood what you're asking :(

Comment: If you're asking for a way to store the scaling status (in this case), the model matrix lets you store also that kind of information, leaving the original vertices unmodified!

Comment: No,no. I'll try to explain. Any transformation of my gizmo (transform, rotate) for selected object changes the model matrix of this object. Two option here: 1)Store primary data of object and to use matrix only for rendering this object. 2) Immediately multiply data by matrix and store brand new data.
Important: I need to use a mouse picking algorythm which work only with modified data, but you say in your answer that "you should not manipulate vertexes". How is this problem solved in 3d editor programs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154567/discussion-between-codenoob-and-magicleon).